# Implementing product of two square matrices in Fortran 95

Tags: matrix, module, fortran, subroutine, fortran95

I need to implement a specific algorithm that calculates the product of 2 square matrices (pre generated in the main program with random numbers) as a subroutine inside a module, like this:

```
module MATMAT

contains

subroutine matmat_ijk

     ...

end subroutine matmat_ijk

end module MATMAT
```

---

This is the algorithm that I have to implement in the subroutine above, cosidering two matrices A(mxr) and B(rxn) to find C(mxn):

```
proc matmat_ijk(real A[1:m,1:r],B[1:r,1:n]; 
                ref real C[1:m,1:n])

1.int i,j,k

2.C:= 0.0

3.for i:=1 until m do

4.for j:=1 until n do

5.for k:=1 until r do

6.C[i,j]:= C[i,j]+A[i,k]*B[k,j]

7.end do

8.end do

9.end do

end proc
```

---

The program will have to call this subroutine matmat_ijk and calculate using the two square matrices (nxn) generated in the main program. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah I know about intrinsic MATMUL and I'll have to use it too, but I need to make this algorithm work so that I can compare the execution time with MATMAL using the HIGH_RES_CLOCK@ (on Silverfrost)! Thanks :)

Comment: @Guidis - Take a crack at it. Here are some keywords to help you out "IMPLICIT NONE", "SIZE", "UBOUND", "LBOUND", "INTENT".